# Unity Navmesh dodge agents - RTS game

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

I'm making a RTS game and I'm having problems when I order my Units to attack

I'm using `NavMesh` and all the units in the game are `NavMeshAgents`, I played with the stopping distance to stop the agents colliding with each other but when they have to attack the enemy they don't detect other agents and instead of surrounding the objective they stack and only one is fighting.

The code I use is very simple

```cs
navmesh.Destination == objective.transform.position;
```

I tried to make all units `navmesh` obstacles but they speed up a lot and start colliding with each other.

I saw other questions related but where from 2014 so maybe are some updated solutions to use in a case like a RTS game.

Could you help me please?